# Problem while installing h5py : Unable to load dependency HDF5, Could not find module 'hdf5.dll'

Tags: python, pip, hdf5, h5py

**When I try to install h5py with "pip install h5py"
, I get this error :**

> Loading library to get build settings and version: hdf5.dll   error:
> **Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly**
> error: **Could not find module 'hdf5.dll'** (or one of its dependencies).
> Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
>
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py Failed to build h5py ERROR:
> **Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be
> installed directly**

- I tried "pip install --upgrade setuptools" and also "pip install --upgrade setuptools --ignore-installed" , and it's do not reslove my problem
- I tried also to downgrade the pip, but it didn't solve the problem though.
  I use python 3.8

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt install build-essential python3.8-dev libhdf5-dev` if on Ubuntu or Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed python 32 bit. Python installation directory will be named Python3.x-32 , if its 32 bit. Uninstall it, and install the 64 bit version